# Reading matrices separated by a newline from file

Tags: c

I need to read two matrices of any dimension from a file in this format:

```
1 2 4
1 3 7
9 2 4 

0 2 4 
1 5 7  
0 2 4
```

The second matrix mustn't necessarily be present. I wrote a code that can already read the first matrix:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;
    int initial_dim = 5;
    int n1 = 0; /*dimension of the first matrix*/
    int n2 = 0; /*dimension of the second matrix*/
    double A[n][n];
    double B[n][n];

    if (argc == 1){
        printf("Please enter file name\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if( (fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL ){
        for(i=0; i < initial_dim; i++)
            for(j=0; j < initial_dim; j++)
                if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &A[i][j]))
                    n1++;

        double x = determinant(n1, A);
        printf("Determinant: %g\n", x);        
        fclose(fp);
    }        

    else{
          printf("I can't open file %s\n", *argv);
          return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need a way to skip the delimiter and read the second matrix

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. When `fscanf("%lf",....)` encounters a blank line, the blank line is simply skipped automatically. In other words the blank lines in your input file don't matter. But you should check the return value of `fscanf` anyway. Read the documentation.

Comment: Furthermore, this code blindly trusts the input to be correctly aligned: it just read 9 values separated from each other with an arbitrary (non null) number of blank characters.

Comment: `initial_dim` is 5 and you are scanning a 5*5 matrix.

Comment: You need one of two things as input - 1. The size of the matrix (n*n) or 2. No of matrices that are input.

Comment: You need to read the matrix first as a 1 dimension array, as you don't know its dimensions. Here you're blindly reading a 5x5 matrix from your 3x3 file, which will fail! For example if you have only one matrix in your file. Moreover, to be able to get the delimiter you can't user fscanf, and should do lower level file accesses, ideally by lines, like with fgetc, and parse these lines... Then you need to set n1, ans maybe even accept non square matrices...

Comment: `printf("I can't open file %s\n", *argv);` will display your program name, I don't think it's what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to write a short answer so I just wrote the code that would do this here: http://gitlab.dotty.fr/dotty/read_matrix/tree/master

The code I wrote can read as many matrices as you want from an input file and store them in a struct. And I think you can modify this code to match what you want to do easily.

If you have any questions please ask me to clarify.

Here is some part of the code to show how simple is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <mat_file>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (mat_parse_next(file))
  {
    struct matrix *mat = mat_read(file);
    mat_dump(mat);
    mat_free(mat);
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to store the two matrices in order to manipulate them. I'd like to be able to multiply them. If you can please add some more comments, for the moment I'm able to calculate the determinant of one matrix http://gitlab.dotty.fr/michmeucci/matrix

Comment: You cant check here(http://gitlab.dotty.fr/dotty/read_matrix/tree/multiply) I just corrected some mistakes in my previous code (in mat_new) and added mat_multiply